# ARMv5 app sometimes crashes - objdump+gdb issue

Tags: multithreading, gdb, qt4, arm, objdump

I have program on arm and sometime it crash.

I study a lot but i don't know what to do.

When program crash it generate coredump file. If i run coredump with binary, backtrace wrote:

```
Core was generated by `./myprog -s -d 731'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x410987e8 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x410987e8 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x41098758 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x41098758 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x41098758 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x41098758 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
and so on same lines......
```

When i modify this program and compile/run again he crash with another lib (libQtGuiE.so) and stack is full with libQtGuiE.so 
some time gdb write "Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)"

strange thing is that i used 4 threads in this program and gdb write this:

```
(gdb) info threads 
  4 Thread 820  0x00000000 in ?? ()
  3 Thread 838  0x00000000 in ?? ()
  2 Thread 835  0x00000000 in ?? ()
* 1 Thread 836  0x410987e8 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

So I think that this means that threads stack was re-written? I used Qt4 - so thread is created by qthread.

The program don't crash a lot -> once per day.

Can you please tell me what to do?

Comment: I also used cppcheck and valgrind -> both are clear